# How does Instagram draw text and sticker in Story?

Tags: android, text, instagram, draw, gesture

I'm writing an app that I can drag, scale, rotate **text** (StaticLayout) and **sticker** (Bitmap) like Instagram Story. I use a custom view to draw objects in *onDraw()*, detect gesture using MotionEvent in *onTouchEvent()*.

But I can't find the bounds which fit these objects, because the bound I use is Rect, and it doesn't fit text/bitmap when I rotate.

Does anyone know how to get the bound that fit these object, or how does Instagram draw text and sticker in Story? OpenGL?

Answer (score 3):

Have you checked this [Signal-Android](https://github.com/signalapp/Signal-Android) repository? They have implemented exactly this feature [here](https://github.com/signalapp/Signal-Android/tree/master/app/src/main/java/org/thoughtcrime/securesms/imageeditor).
If you are new to this repo and find yourself in trouble running this project, you can use the [playstore app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.thoughtcrime.securesms&hl=en) to see how it functions and explore the codebase parallelly.